# HTTP Status [404] не обнаруживантся jsp

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlet

Вот такой простейший сервлет:

```
public class UserServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {

        req.setAttribute("name", "my_name");

        req.getRequestDispatcher("user.jsp").forward(req, resp);

    }
}
```

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>UserServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>ru.pravvich.servlets.UserServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>UserServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Сам user.jsp

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>user</title>
</head>
<body>

    <h1>name : ${name}</h1>


</body>
</html>
```

И лог который говорит что все типо хорошо:

```
/Users/pavel/apache-tomcat-8.5.15/bin/catalina.sh run
[2017-05-27 02:34:04,444] Artifact chapter_009: Server is not connected. Deploy is not available.
[2017-05-27 02:34:04,445] Artifact junior (1):war exploded: Server is not connected. Deploy is not available.
Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:51749', transport: 'socket'
27-May-2017 02:34:11.359 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version:        Apache Tomcat/8.5.15
27-May-2017 02:34:11.362 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:          May 5 2017 11:03:04 UTC
27-May-2017 02:34:11.363 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server number:         8.5.15.0
27-May-2017 02:34:11.363 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:               Mac OS X
27-May-2017 02:34:11.363 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:            10.12.5
27-May-2017 02:34:11.363 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:          x86_64
27-May-2017 02:34:11.363 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:             /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_101.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
27-May-2017 02:34:11.363 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:           1.8.0_101-b13
27-May-2017 02:34:11.363 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
27-May-2017 02:34:11.364 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:         /Users/pavel/Library/Caches/IntelliJIdea2016.2/tomcat/Unnamed_junior_2
27-May-2017 02:34:11.364 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:         /Users/pavel/apache-tomcat-8.5.15
27-May-2017 02:34:11.365 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/Users/pavel/Library/Caches/IntelliJIdea2016.2/tomcat/Unnamed_junior_2/conf/logging.properties
27-May-2017 02:34:11.365 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
27-May-2017 02:34:11.365 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=127.0.0.1:51749,suspend=y,server=n
27-May-2017 02:34:11.365 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=
27-May-2017 02:34:11.365 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1099
27-May-2017 02:34:11.365 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
27-May-2017 02:34:11.366 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
27-May-2017 02:34:11.366 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=127.0.0.1
27-May-2017 02:34:11.366 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048
27-May-2017 02:34:11.366 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources
27-May-2017 02:34:11.366 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=/Users/pavel/Library/Caches/IntelliJIdea2016.2/tomcat/Unnamed_junior_2
27-May-2017 02:34:11.366 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=/Users/pavel/apache-tomcat-8.5.15
27-May-2017 02:34:11.367 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=/Users/pavel/apache-tomcat-8.5.15/temp
27-May-2017 02:34:11.367 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [/Users/pavel/Library/Java/Extensions:/Library/Java/Extensions:/Network/Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Library/Java/Extensions:/usr/lib/java:.]
27-May-2017 02:34:11.578 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
27-May-2017 02:34:11.720 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
27-May-2017 02:34:11.730 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
27-May-2017 02:34:11.733 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
27-May-2017 02:34:11.734 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Initialization processed in 1053 ms
27-May-2017 02:34:11.794 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service [Catalina]
27-May-2017 02:34:11.795 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.15
27-May-2017 02:34:11.849 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
27-May-2017 02:34:11.877 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
27-May-2017 02:34:11.882 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 147 ms
Connected to server
[2017-05-27 02:34:12,066] Artifact chapter_009: Artifact is being deployed, please wait...
[2017-05-27 02:34:12,067] Artifact junior (1):war exploded: Artifact is being deployed, please wait...
[2017-05-27 02:34:12,866] Artifact chapter_009: Artifact is deployed successfully
[2017-05-27 02:34:12,866] Artifact chapter_009: Deploy took 800 milliseconds
27-May-2017 02:34:13.141 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(6)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
[2017-05-27 02:34:13,166] Artifact junior (1):war exploded: Artifact is deployed successfully
[2017-05-27 02:34:13,166] Artifact junior (1):war exploded: Deploy took 1 099 milliseconds
27-May-2017 02:34:21.858 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/Users/pavel/apache-tomcat-8.5.15/webapps/manager]
27-May-2017 02:34:21.935 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/Users/pavel/apache-tomcat-8.5.15/webapps/manager] has finished in [68] ms
```

Модуль собирается в war так что тут проблем не должно быть

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<artifactId>chapter_009</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
```

Структура проекта:
[image: Структура проекта]

И в итоге получаю

```
HTTP Status [404] – [Not Found]

Type Status Report

Message /items/user.jsp

Description The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.

Apache Tomcat/8.5.15
```

Подскажите пожалуйста в чем тут может быть проблема? Спасибо.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Во-первых, `HttpServletRequest.getRequestDispatcher()` использует относительные пути, поэтому будет искать файл user.jsp относительно контекста сервлета, то есть в вашем случае в items. А у вас, судя по ошибке, нет jsp-страницы, доступной по адресу /items/user.jsp. Во-вторых, в [Java™ Servlet Specification version 3.1](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/servlet-3_1-fr-eval-spec/index.html) написано:

> A special directory exists within the application hierarchy named
>   WEB-INF. This directory contains all things related to the application
>   that aren’t in the document root of the application. **The WEB-INF node
>   is not part of the public document tree of the application.** No file
>   contained in the WEB-INF directory may be served directly to a client
>   by the container. However, the contents of the WEB-INF directory are
>   visible to servlet code using the getResource and getResourceAsStream
>   method calls on the ServletContext, and may be exposed using the
>   RequestDispatcher calls.

Проще говоря, не надо складывать туда jsp-файлы. Особенно, если они не обрабатываются каким-либо шаблонизатором.

Переложите user.jsp в корень webapp.